# python sys.stdin.read() from tail -f

Tags: python, linux, bash, stdin, geoip

How come sys.stdin.read() doesn't read the piped input from tail -f?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from geoip import geolite2
def iplookup(srcip):
        for ip in srcip.split("\n"):
                try:
                        print(geolite2.lookup(ip))
                except:
                        pass
source = sys.stdin.read()
iplookup(source)
```

`tail -f /var/log/bleh.log | grep -oE '((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])' | python mygeoip.py`

Comment: 1. are you certain there is output to read, and 2. `sys.stdin.read()` *blocks* until there is no more data to read, I suspect that in this case that'll never be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sys.stdin` as an iterator, rather than trying to read from it first.

```
def iplookup(srcip):
    for ip in srcip:
        ip = ip.strip()
        try:
            print(geolite2.lookup(ip))
        except:
            pass

iplookup(sys.stdin)
```

Comment: This does not work with `tail -f` here using Python 2.7.12.

Comment: @cweiske, can you provide a reproducer for that? It certainly *should* work -- won't return, of course, but the goal isn't that the function ever returns, but that it prints new lookup results as content is streamed in. I wonder if the issue is buffering-related, which would require knowing more about the "here" and the test procedure to speak to (ie. how many items are added to the file, and whether it's enough to exceed the `LINE_MAX*10` maximum buffer size guaranteed by the POSIX standard for `tail`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fileinput` :

```
import sys
from geoip import geolite2
import fileinput

def iplookup(srcip):
        for ip in srcip.split("\n"):
                try:
                        print(geolite2.lookup(ip))
                except:
                        pass

for line in fileinput.input():
    iplookup(line)
```

On the plus side, your script automagically accepts filename as parameters as well.

Answer (score 3):

None of the other answers (even `fileinput`) fully addresses the issue of buffering, and so will not work for small outputs of `tail -f`.

From [the python man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/python):

> Note that there is internal buffering in xreadlines(), readlines() and
>   file-object iterators ("for line in sys.stdin") which is not
>   influenced by this option. To work around this, you will want to use
>   "sys.stdin.readline()" inside a "while 1:" loop.

In other words what you want is:

```
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    iplookup(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

read() reads until EOF is reached.
EOF char is added when close() is performed or you can add it explicitly.

Your file does not have any EOF. Modify your program to read blocks of fixed size or iterate over leadline() instead.